# FreeBSD 2 network cards

Tags: configuration, freebsd, linux-networking, local-area-network

We have server with 2 network cards with *FreeBSD* on it. 1 card used for internet (works fine) and another one for local network connection (to **192.168.227.0/24** net). When i try to ping gateway of local network with ip **192.168.227.1** i got message **"ping: send to: host is down."** The gateway is OK and online - all other servers (with Ubuntu) can easely connect to this network. *So maybe i have some errors in my configuration files.*

***ifconfig:***

```
igb0: flags=8802<BROADCAST,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=1bb<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,JUMBO_MTU,VLAN_HWCSUM,              TSO4>
        ether 3c:d9:2b:f2:d1:f6
        media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
        status: active
igb1: flags=8802<BROADCAST,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=1bb<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,JUMBO_MTU,VLAN_HWCSUM,              TSO4>
        ether 3c:d9:2b:f2:d1:f7
        media: Ethernet autoselect
        status: no carrier
em0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=219b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,TSO4,WOL_              MAGIC>
        ether 00:26:55:ea:e3:a6
        inet 77.195.133.102 netmask 0xffffffe0 broadcast 77.195.133.127
        media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
        status: active
em1: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=19b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,TSO4>
        ether 00:26:55:ea:e3:a7
        inet 192.168.227.24 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.227.255
        media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
        status: active
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
        options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
        inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5
        inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
        nd6 options=3<PERFORMNUD,ACCEPT_RTADV>
```

***netstat -r***

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags    Refs      Use  Netif Expire
default            77.195.133.97      UGS         9  2874633    em0
10.6.200.0         192.168.227.1      UGS         0        0    em1
77.195.133.96/27   link#3             U           3  3808304    em0
77.195.133.102     link#3             UHS         0        0    lo0
localhost          link#5             UH          0     2101    lo0
192.168.227.0      link#4             U           0       59    em1
192.168.227.24     link#4             UHS         0        0    lo0

Internet6:
Destination        Gateway            Flags      Netif Expire
localhost          localhost          UH          lo0
fe80::%lo0         link#5             U           lo0
fe80::1%lo0        link#5             UHS         lo0
ff01:5::           fe80::1%lo0        U           lo0
ff02::%lo0         fe80::1%lo0        U           lo0
```

***/etc/rc.conf***

```
defaultrouter="77.195.133.97"
hostname="bd-mor-online.myhost.ru"
ifconfig_em0="inet 77.195.133.102 netmask 255.255.255.224"
ifconfig_em1="inet 192.168.227.24 netmask 255.255.255.0"
static_routes="net1 net2"
route_net1="-net 192.168.227.0/24 192.168.227.1"
route_net2="-net 10.6.200.0/24 192.168.227.1"
keymap="ru.koi8-r"
sshd_enable="YES"
inetd_enable="YES"
linux_enable="YES"
```

**ping -c5 192.168.227.24 is OK - 100%.**

There also the network **10.6.200.0** where i need route this server via **192.168.227.1**, but the **main goal is to get PING's from gateway**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn on ip forwarding with
the following setting in `/etc/rc.conf`

> gateway_enable="YES"

Comment: Don't know can it help or not - our system administrator too silly to try it on working server, so she just reconfigured igb0 interface for that network and everything work fine now. Thanks for help anyway.

Comment: You can also set it on the fly with sysctl.  Set net.inet.ip.forwarding=1. Optionally to improve performance also set net.inet.ip.fastforwarding=1